# Selecting value from a dropdown list on a webpage using vba

Tags: vba, excel, webautomation

On [this site](https://visa.kdmid.ru/PetitionChoice.aspx) I am able to select the country and language from dropdown menu but when I click on "Complete new application form" button. It says fields are empty.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Test()

strURL = "https://visa.kdmid.ru/PetitionChoice.aspx"

  With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate strURL

    While .Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Set html = .document

    'Country where you will apply for visa.
    Set ctY = html.getElementById("ctl00$phBody$Country")
    For i = 1 To ctY.Options.Length
        If ctY.Options(i).Text = "NETHERLANDS" Then
            ctY.selectedIndex = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    'Select Language
    Set lnG = html.getElementById("ctl00$phBody$ddlLanguage")
    For i = 1 To lnG.Options.Length
        If lnG.Options(i).Text = "ENGLISH" Then
            lnG.selectedIndex = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    'Click I have read instructions check box
    html.getElementById("ctl00$phBody$cbConfirm").Click


    'Click apply button
    Set btnGo = html.forms(0).all("ctl00$phBody$btnNewApplication") 
    btnGo.Click

  End With

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are on the right track but if you look at the HTML of the site there are actually two elements with the country selection- you got the first one, 'ctl00_phBody_Country', but this is actually just the drop down, and the actual selected value is stored in 'ctl00_phBody_cddCountry_ClientState'... the language section has similar structure. Lastly the accepted value is not just the country name you see in the drop down, it is actually a combination of a country code from the drop down and the country name....

See below for sample code:

```
Public Sub Test()
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument

Dim countryStr As String
Dim countryObj As HTMLObjectElement
Dim countryCodes As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim codeCounter As Long
Dim languageStr As String
Dim languageObj As HTMLObjectElement
Dim languageCodes As IHTMLElementCollection

countryStr = "Netherlands"
languageStr = "English"

Set IE = New InternetExplorer

With IE
    .Visible = False
    .Navigate "https://visa.kdmid.ru/PetitionChoice.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1"
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Wend
    Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
End With

Set countryObj = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_phBody_cddCountry_ClientState")
Set countryCodes = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_phBody_Country").getElementsByTagName("option")
For codeCounter = 0 To countryCodes.Length - 1
    If countryCodes(codeCounter).innerText = UCase(countryStr) Then
        countryObj.Value = countryCodes(codeCounter).Value & ":::" & countryCodes(codeCounter).innerText & ":::"
        While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Wend
        Exit For
    End If
Next

Set languageObj = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_phBody_cddLanguage_ClientState")
Set languageCodes = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_phBody_ddlLanguage").getElementsByTagName("option")
For codeCounter = 0 To languageCodes.Length - 1
    If languageCodes(codeCounter).innerText = UCase(languageStr) Then
        languageObj.Value = languageCodes(codeCounter).Value & ":::" & languageCodes(codeCounter).innerText & ":::"
        While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Wend
        Exit For
    End If
Next

HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00$phBody$cbConfirm").Click
While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Wend
HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_phBody_btnNewApplication").Click      'Launch Form

IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort but when I run this I get the same error of fields being empty.

Comment: Hmm, I just re-ran it again on my end to double check and worked fine- the drop downs look blank but when I advance to the next screen I do not get any errors... 

Perhaps youre missing references? Only thing i could think of- Make sure both 'Microsoft HTML Object Library' and 'Microsoft Internet Controls' are added.

Comment: I had it referenced the libraries it doesn't work on my end can you send me your version of the file maybe? Because I took your code from the answer as it is still doesn't works.

Comment: Perhaps its a setting on your IE- I know that if you have a certain security level enabled making changes to webpage data in IE is not allowed...