# How to select a time in a time picker while web-scraping in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to select 09 from the time picker below using excel VBA. I have got as far as the line below but do not know how to proceed. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
Set e = appIE.document.getElementbyid("timepicker-pickup")


<div class="timepicker" id="timepicker-pickup">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        <div class="icon close-btn"></div>
        <div class="inner-time-picker clearfix">
            <div class="section hours">
                <div class="up-arrow"><span class="icon arrow"></span></div>
                <div class="selectors">
                    <ul>
                        <li data-value="00">00</li>
                        <li data-value="01">01</li>
                        <li data-value="02">02</li>
                        <li data-value="03">03</li>
                        <li data-value="04">04</li>
                        <li data-value="05">05</li>
                        <li data-value="06">06</li>
                        <li data-value="07">07</li>
                        <li data-value="08" class="selected">08</li>
                        <li data-value="09">09</li>
                        <li data-value="10">10</li>
                        <li data-value="11">11</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="down-arrow"><span class="icon arrow"></span></div>
```

Comment: Can you also give the sweb site you are trying to scrap?

Comment: @Vityata https://www.europcar.co.za/

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41688620/selecting-value-from-a-dropdown-list-on-a-webpage-using-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[CSS selectors:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)**

Try selector `#timepicker-pickup li:nth-child(10)`

```
appIE.document.querySelector("#timepicker-pickup li:nth-child(10)").Click
```

The `#` means className and so selects the 10th `li` tag within element with className `timepicker-pickup`

or selector `#timepicker-pickup [data-value='09']`

```
appIE.document.querySelector("#timepicker-pickup *[data-value='09']").Click
```

This is simply an abbreviation where I look for anything with  attribute `data-value='09'` within the className of `timepicker-pickup`

I tested with the latest which works.

---

**CSS selector:**

[image: CSS query]

---

**VBA code:**

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer, URL As String

    URL = "https://www.europcar.co.za/"
    Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer

    With ieApp
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.querySelector("#timepicker-pickup [data-value='09']").Click

        Stop '<== Delete me
        '.Quit <'== Uncomment me
    End With
End Sub
```