# How to select from a list while web-scraping with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to select a time from a time picker on a website with the excel VBA code below. While the code loops through it does not select 09. What am I doing wrong? Website code also below.

```
Set e = appIE.document.getElementbyid("timepicker-pickup").getElementsByTagName("li")
     For Each e In e
      If e.innerHTML = "09" Then
      e.Click
      End If
    Next
```

Website code:

```
<div class="timepicker" id="timepicker-pickup">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="icon close-btn"></div>
    <div class="inner-time-picker clearfix">
        <div class="section hours">
            <div class="up-arrow"><span class="icon arrow"></span></div>
            <div class="selectors">
                <ul>
                    <li data-value="00">00</li>
                    <li data-value="01">01</li>
                    <li data-value="02">02</li>
                    <li data-value="03">03</li>
                    <li data-value="04">04</li>
                    <li data-value="05">05</li>
                    <li data-value="06">06</li>
                    <li data-value="07">07</li>
                    <li data-value="08" class="selected">08</li>
                    <li data-value="09">09</li>
                    <li data-value="10">10</li>
                    <li data-value="11">11</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Not sure if this will resolve your problem but it certainly not good programming practice. You are using `e` as your container and your object. Try using a different name for the actual object i.e. `For Each i In e`. You can then try `i.Click`

Comment: It's a definite duplicate of this thread: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46559907/how-to-select-a-time-in-a-time-picker-while-web-scraping-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim iL as iHTMLElement
Dim e As IHTMLElementCollection

Set e = appIE.document.getElementbyid("timepicker-pickup").getElementsByTagName("li")
For Each iL In e
  If il.innerText = "09" Then
  iL.Click
  End If
Next iL
```

Comment: I am receiving a Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method here: If f.innerText = "09" Then  Are you able to help with what might be causing this?

Comment: type ?e.innerHTML in Immediate window and tell me what can you see.

Comment: When put this : ?e.innerHTML in the immediate window it gives a Run-time error '424' Object required.

Comment: it looks lke e wasn't initialized. You may try ?typename(e), if it is Nothing then we know that the things went wrong by: Set e = appIE.document.getElementbyid("timepicker-pickup").getElementsByTagName("li")

Comment: or depending on which line I am on it gives me the same Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: I receive the following: ?typename(e)
HTMLSelectElement

Comment: Sorrry! I receive this: DispHTMLElementCollection

Comment: I can see. Change this line to il.innerText = "09" then

Comment: Thank you it works now. You are a scholar and gentleman. Your patience and help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use querySelector of:

```
appIE.document.querySelector("#timepicker-pickup *[data-value='09']").Click
```

No loop required.